# How to connect from Flexible Environment to Second Generation Cloud SQL instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have deployed my web server which requires a MySQL database for storage. I've created a Second Generation MySQL instance with one failover replica but I am not sure how I can connect to those.

I am not sure how to configure these instances and what I have to consider here e.g. region/zone. Flexible Environment appears to be unavailable in Europe unfortunately - at the moment at least - so I guess I'll have to place the SQL instances in the US too.

Will those instances have to be in the same local network or can they communicate over regions? Will I even be able to control this or will all this be decided by Google Cloud?

Could anybody who has done this before give me a few details about what to do here?

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, you should place your App Engine instances in the same region.

For information on how to connect from your application to the Cloud SQL MySQL instance see the following documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/dev-access#gaev2-csqlv2

The short summary is that you have to modify your app.yaml file to list the Cloud SQL instances you will be connecting to. Once that's done, a local socket will appear inside the App Engine VM that will allow you to connect to your Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: Hi! That looks rather straight forward - except the part "*connect to the instance by opening a socket with the following name: `/cloudsql/[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}`*". If I had `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mz_db?useSSL=false` locally, would I change this to `jdbc:mysql://cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME/mz_db?useSSL=false`?

Comment: Or would I just connect to the internal IPv4 address `w.x.y.z:3306`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were connecting from Java. For Java, you would use this library: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-mysql-socket-factory You will have trouble connecting directly by IP because you have to authorize which IPs are allowed to connect to your instance and App Engine VM IPs can change as new instances are created.